# Expanding a configuration stub into builder and value using macros

Tags: scala, types, macros

More a *hypothetical* question. Is it *possible*, using Scala macros, to turn a structure like this:

```
object Foo extends Factory {  // Factory = expansion magic
  trait Config {
    val i: Int = 33
    val s: String = "foo"
  }

  def apply(c: Config): Foo = ???
}
trait Foo
```

(more or less automatically) into this:

```
object Foo {
  sealed trait ConfigLike {
    def i: Int
    def s: String
  }
  object Config {
    def apply() = new ConfigBuilder
    implicit def build(b: ConfigBuilder) = b.build
  }
  final case class Config(i: Int, s: String) extends ConfigLike
  object ConfigBuilder {
    def apply(c: Config) = {
      val b = new ConfigBuilder
      b.read(c)
      b
    }
  }
  final class ConfigBuilder extends ConfigLike {
    var i: Int = 33
    var s: String = "foo"
    def build: Config = Config(i, s)
    def read(c: Config) {
      i = c.i
      s = c.s
    }
  }

  def apply(c: Config = Config()): Foo = ???
}
```

Use case:

```
val c = Foo.Config()
c.i = 44
c.s = "bar"
val f = Foo(c)
```

Is this what paradise type-macros are for?

If so, why would anyone want to stop the development of type-macros?

Comment: I think that's definitely what type macros that return `Template` trees are for, like the last example in [this doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/typemacros.html#intuition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's what type macros were designed to do. They were abandoned, because they can also do other things that we are not sure about exposing. Nevertheless, we recognize the value of codegeneration, and at the moment we are exploring other avenues to achieve it (e.g. macro annotations).